# Longest certified DisplayPort cable that supports AMD FreeSync

Tags: display-port

I can't seem to find any certified cables over 10ft let alone the few that specify a version.

Preferably I need one that is `> 10ft` but could be `<= 15ft`.

At minimum it just needs to support `1.2a` but I'd prefer `1.3` or `1.4`.

My GPU supports 1.4 but current monitor only supports 1.2 *(& AMD FreeSync)*.

Cable needs to support `2560x1440@60`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR: Active cables, choose a length.

Normal DisplayPort (passive) cables cap out at 3 meters. These cables are basically just bundles of copper with connectors at each end.

However, you can get more expensive active cables that use electronics built into the cable to extend the range. [These cap out at 33 meters](https://www.engadget.com/2011/06/22/displayport-1-2-adds-active-cable-support-brings-longer-cords/), though the longest I could find for sale is [15 meters.](https://www.startech.com/Cables/Audio-Video/DisplayPort/15m-Active-DisplayPort-Cable-M-M~DISPL15MA) Note that these really are expensive though, with that cable costing about $80.

Because these cables have built in electronics, make sure you read the specifications for each cable to ensure compatibility. FreeSync should be good pretty much no matter what, but check resolution, audio, directionality, and HDCP support. The 15m cable I linked supports a unidirectional 2560x1600@60Hz signal with audio and HDCP.

If for some reason you need to go more than 15m, you can run [DisplayPort over CAT5](https://www.cablestogo.com/category/displayport/displayport-extenders). If you've got money to burn, or need to maintain a high bandwith connection an extremely long distance, there are [optical DisplayPort cables](http://www.dvigear.com/cables-dp-aoc.html) and [more generic DisplayPort to optical](http://www.gefen.com/product/displayport-extender-over-two-lc-fiber-optic-cables-EXT-DP-CP-2FO) converters, starting at $270 for 3 meters and going to $1750 for 100 meters or $1000 flat for the converters. If you start getting concerned about caring other data along for the ride, you could use an optical Thunderbolt cable, which along with other data, can carry a DisplayPort connection up to 60m. [It does cost $1000 though.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01BX6KAOK)

Comment: Ah, good to know. Surprisingly, none of those came up in search results but I wasn't searching too wide. The title was under the presumption that passive cables were maybe all there was and I was hoping for a `4m` cable but only finding `3m` at most.

Comment: This one came up which seems promising although I can't confirm that it's certified (https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B06XSV3B4L)

Comment: @Enigma It doesn't brand itself as an active cable explicitly, but that cable seems to have some pretty good specs and Club3D has a good reputation (especially compatibility with AMD cards), so given the pretty low price of that cable and Amazon's return policy, I say go for it!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want a dedicated displayport repeater as cables often break.

Keep in mind the further you go the higher your latency will be, and the more repeater you'll need. Only go this route if you absolutely need it.

Comment: Repeaters are super expensive and require another power source at what's usually an inconvenient location. IMO active cables are a much better solution.

Comment: I'm seeing that now. Jeez, digital repeaters are expensive. Makes me miss analog. Still I'd say buying a repeater has pros that should be considered, durability first among them. I'm seeing repeaters on amazon in the $80 range, and I'd reckon you can find cheaper ones on ebay for less.    Wires are almost always the first point of failure in any setup.

Comment: Active cables tend to be much better quality than cheap passive ones, but yes, your point is valid. If you're really concerned about durability, I'd go with optics.

Comment: I'm a bit unfamiliar with optics. Do you have any resources to help brush up on them?

Comment: Sorry, optical cables. Take a look at the latter part of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Great information as always.